# Does Event Hub read its own Capture files?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventhub

I've read multiple articles describing how the Event Hub "Capture Feature" can be used to retain messages beyond 7 days using Blob Storage or Data Lake; but none say if those messages can be replayed to a Consumer if it were to rewind the Offset backwards beyond 7 days.

Should I assume the Capture feature claim is a little "tongue in cheek" and in actuality it's an export feature and does not integrate with or extend Event Hub's native transient storage?

Thanks

-John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct. The capture feature just stores the data into blob storage or ADLS, but it cannot be used to replay by just rewinding the Offset backwards beyond 7 days.

If you want to replay, you need to resend the data from storage to eventhub again. Here is [an example](https://github.com/msatmsft/event-hub-replay) of reading the captured data, you can take use of it and re-send it by yourself for replay purpose.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you Ivan, did you forget to attach a link to the sample?

Comment: @JohnKoz, my bad. The link is [here](https://github.com/msatmsft/event-hub-replay).